# Share Service account file in another user Google Drive using PHP Google Client

Tags: php, google-drive-api, share, service-accounts

I am using PHP Google Client code and I am using service account too. I completed the following codes using service account:

1. Creating a folder that anyone can access.
2. Insert a file in that folder that anyone can also access.

It worked with following Google drive share link and also shared to other email, also `https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7DT8HrNe_iDQkhnQ3REMkxwM2M`.

But my question is, I am sharing a file to a single user with PHP Google Client and automatically that user gets the file in their Google Drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Kindly rephrase the question. What you're trying to point out is vague.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?